# "how to fix :org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed

Tags: jenkins-groovy

In progress of creating the first stage in pipeline , i have got this script for the stage 1

i have created a pipeline , and i have installed the pipeline plugin and i have deleted the 16 line and 15 line i keep getting errors

node {

```
            stage('Checkout') {
                            echo('Checkout code from Github')   
                            checkout([$class: 'GitSCM', branches: [[name: '*/developer']], doGenerateSubmoduleConfigurations: false, extensions: [], submoduleCfg: [], userRemoteConfigs: [[url: 'https://github.dxc.com/DXCLabsIndia/Store-Assist']]])
            }
            try {
            stage('Quality Scan') {
                            echo('Running SonarJS')
                            dir(''){
                            bat "npm install sonarjs"
                            bat "sonarjs"
                            }
                            }
            } catch (e) {
                echo(Quality scan had voilations,Fix all major ones)
    result = "Quality scan had voilations" // make sure other exceptions are recorded as failure too
```

}

my desired result should be able to compile it

Comment: the first part i was able to fix it

Comment: Any chance you might share how you fixed the first part please?